# S3 using boto and SigV4 - missing host parameter

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

when developing i used a S3 bucket in ireland, which worked well. For production i want to use the new "Frankfurt" location of S3, but apparently the new Frankfurt region uses the "SigV4" which breaks my python script.

When adding the following block to ~/.boto, i get the following error:

~/.boto:

```
[s3]
use-sigv4 = True
```

Error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/__init__.py", line 141, in connect_s3
return S3Connection(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 196, in __init__
"When using SigV4, you must specify a 'host' parameter."
boto.s3.connection.HostRequiredError: BotoClientError: When using SigV4, 
you must specify a 'host' parameter.
```

Can anybody please tell me how to specify the "host" parameter? I couldn't find this parameter in a aws/boto documentation.

Comment: if you only want to use sigv4 for eu-central (very ugly): `os.environ['S3_USE_SIGV4'] = 'True'` then after you are done `del os.environ['S3_USE_SIGV4']` so that you don't have to provide a `host` for older code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Here's the docs for your exact error](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3.connection), as well as the [exact source code](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/s3/connection.py#L167) that's creating the `S3Connection` (and in turn, your error).

In creating the `S3Connection(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, **kwargs)`, you need to pass in an additional item `host=...`, which should be a simple string like `'s3.amazonaws.com'`, or similar for your setup.

**Solution:**

You can add this to your `kwargs` being passed:

```
kwargs.update({'host': 's3.amazonaws.com'})
```

or call it manually like:

```
S3Connection(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, host='s3.amazonaws.com', **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you, i managed to get the script working with your example. Do you also know if there is a possibility to provide the host parameter in the boto config file?

Comment: You'd have to give the value from the boto.cfg file yourself. The function seems to pull a default value from the config, but only after it's already flagged to produce an error. So, you'll *have* to provide it in the instantiation of the `S3Connection`. Now, that can come from the config, but it's up to you to do that.